# Outputting the keys of the max value of a hash within Arrays in Ruby using methods

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, max

```
data = [
  "Company one" => {
    "number_1" => 46,
    "number_2" => 3055,
    "country" => "USA"
      },
  "Company two" => {
    "number_1" => 32,
    "number_2" => 6610,
    "country" => "USA"
      },
 "Company three" => {
    "number_1" => 40,
    "number_2" => 9128,
    "country" => "USA"
     }
]
```

So I have this array in which I'm trying to get which of the company has the biggest number in 'number_2'. The largest would be Company three with 9128.

So I have this code that puts the largest number which would be 9128

```
 def number(data)
          collected_array=[]
          data.each do |company_hash|
           collected_array =  company_hash.map do |k,v|
                 v["number_2"]
             end
           end
         puts collected_array.max
         end
         number(data)
```

But I'm trying to puts the company name  with the largest number which would be "Company three". I've tried `.keys` and  other ways but it gives me error.
I've tried this way:

```
def number(data)
  collected_array=[]
  data.each do |company_hash|
   collected_array =  company_hash.map do |k,v|
         v["number_2"]
         k
     end
   end
 puts collected_array.max
 end
 number(data)
```

but it gives me "Company two" rather than "Company three" which would be the company with the highest number

Comment: Can you corroborate the format of the content inside `data`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. corroborate as in?

Comment: It looks like it would be better as a Hash containing `Company one`, `Company two`, etc. Now is a hash, and inspecting the elements, it's making more difficult to work with it.

Comment: while that would be better. I can't modify anything inside the `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Cary, it can be simplified accessing the first element on data, and there using max_by, on the hash local variable available within the block checking the `number_2` key value.

As the result is an Array containing two elements, the first one is the company name, the second and last one, the hash containing its data:

```
data = [
  "Company one" => {
    "number_1" => 46,
    "number_2" => 3055,
    "country" => "USA"
  },
  "Company two" => {
    "number_1" => 32,
    "number_2" => 6610,
    "country" => "USA"
  },
  "Company three" => {
    "number_1" => 40,
    "number_2" => 9128,
    "country" => "USA"
  }
]

max_company = data.first.max_by { |_, h| h['number_2'] }

p max_company.first # "Company three"
p max_company.last['number_2'] # 9128
```